# Can reach local DNS, but remote not

Tags: dns, dig

I'm getting nowhere with the following problem: When using my local ISPs DNS server at `192.168.0.1` (for example putting it into `/etc/resolv.conf` or using it directly with `dig google.com @192.168.0.1`) everything works fine, all names are resolved. But as soon as I use **any** other DNS server (`8.8.8.8`, `9.9.9.9` or `1.1.1.1` - e.g. `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`) nothing works, I get the following error message from `dig`

```
$ dig google.com @8.8.8.8
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> google.com @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

What I did so far:

- Used `ping 8.8.8.8` to check if I have net access - everything works.
- Checked if the firewall port `53` is open - yes, it is.
- Checked `tcpdump -i eth0 -n -S port 53` - `dig` sends out the requests, I get no responses.

The strange thing is that when I use `192.168.0.1` as the DNS server it works, but as soon as I use **any** other DNS server I get no response. Can anyone help?

Comment: @shiftas 1h ago it worked properly and suddenly it stopped working. I can not explain why, I did nothing unusual. I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: For port 53, is TCP **and** UDP open?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes, exactly, both TCP and UDP.

Comment: A good test would be in a friend with the same Internet package just to rule out some configuration mishap on your side. You might have a cheap package where your provider might be blocking port 53 for the Internet at large. Seen it happen. An alternative is having a local DNS cache/server talking DoT or DoH with the outside world.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - Imagine, after calling my ISP (of course, they denied that they made any changes to their system during the phone call) it suddenly began to work. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: ISP operation mistake probably...it happens.

Comment: Quick note. ISPs using cable modem can apply port filtering rules at the CPE/modem level, for instance, blocking non-IP packets and packets talking with port 53 ;)

Comment: "no servers could be reached" is a transport issue. Flags that can help: `+tcp` to force TCP or `+notcp` to force UDP (DNS is a poor child being mistreated regarding UDP vs TCP it often happens some rules are on one transport and not the other), and then working on EDNS UDP buffer size (`+bufsize`). BTW `ping` is almost never a good tool for troubleshooting. You could instead use `tcptraceroute 8.8.8.8 53` to check TCP connectivity to host or `traceroute --udp` which uses port 53 then by default.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - great advices regarding `traceroute` - thanks!